# How do I connect to a specific instance of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I believe I have MS SQL Server version 2005, and version 2008 (x64), on my computer. When I connect to localhost in SQL Server Management Studio 2008, the tree on the left says "localhost (SQL Server 9.0.4053)". Also, running:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')
```

returns 9.00.4053.00.

How do I select 2008 as the version I wish to use?

Comment: 2008 has version 10.0.1600.22

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your instances should have names.

By accessing localhost you will get the first instance.

Another intance can be accessed with localhost\INSTANCENAME

Answer (score 0):

To get the instance names you can take a short look in the services list, every instance has a service contanining the instance name.
HTH

Comment: I'd +1, but I don't have enough reputation. Thanks, that helped!

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to hear it helped.